# Path is not writable within container

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, permissions

I have a Laravel app running in a docker container and am running into `Path "/var/www/app/storage/clockwork" is not writable.` According to the info Laravel provides, the user is `www-data`. Originally it showed that '1000' and '1001' where the user and group that owned the directory. I modified the uid and gid for www-data user and group to match those within the container. `ls -l` shows the following:

`drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 10 19:01 clockwork`

If the www-data user owns the directory I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to write to the directory. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently restarting the container was what I needed to do. After shutting down and coming back to it, everything worked.

Comment: didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Double check the user for both your web server (ex: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) and if you're using PHP-FPM the user for that as well (depends on the distro but something like /etc/php/VERSION/fpm/php-fpm.conf).

Make sure that the user has execute permissions on all of the parent directories (in your case /var /var/www /var/www/app and /var/www/app/storage). You should be able to "stat" the directory using that user `sudo -u www-data stat /var/www/app/storage/clockwork`.

If the directory is mounted to the container from a host machine there are some known issues with that as well depending on the OS etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently I just needed to restart the container.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue with Laravel Clockwork and PHP Deployer - although evidently the issue manifests similarly in Docker too - and there are two possible solutions. The first is the easiest and fastest, while the second is the more involved, "proper" way and the least likely to cause issues in the future.

---

### Solution 1: modify user permissions

You can modify the owner of `clockwork`'s parent directories, which in my case were owned by `root` by default, by running each of the following commands:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/yourappname/shared/storage
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/yourappname/shared/storage/clockwork
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/yourappname/shared/storage/clockwork/index
```

The commands above modify the owner of each of these directories to the user `hashim` and then add that user to the `www-data` group. `www-data` is the name of both a user and group that exists on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu with the sole purpose of serving websites.

[More information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873839/what-is-the-www-data-user) on the `www-data` user-group.

---

### Solution 2: make Clockwork a dev dependency

Because Clockwork is ultimately a developer dependency (a package needed for local development purposes) it can be safely left out on the server completely, which prevents the `clockwork` directory from ever being created and sidesteps the permissions issue completely.

To do this, first move the `clockwork` line in your `composer.json` from `require` to `require_dev`:

```
# composer.json

"require": {
    ...
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.1", // remove from here
},


"require-dev": {
    ...
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.1", // add to here
 }
```

Next, you'll need to modify `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider` to only load Clockwork's service provider if the package is installed (and enabled):

```
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->environment('local') && config('clockwork.enable')) {
        $this->app->register(\Clockwork\Support\Laravel\ClockworkServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

Finally, run `composer dump-autoload`.